# How to obtain java.sql.Time in GMT

Tags: java, time

I have an object `java.sql.Time` from which I need to obtain the time in millisecond. I can not use `getTime()` function. I noticed that there is a deprecated function `getTimeZoneOffset`. So, I don't want to use it. What else can I use? I am also using JVM 7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Why* can't you use `getTime()`?  It does exactly what you want and isn't deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned `java.sql.Time` is highly deprecated, you can convert it easily to a `Calendar` instance (since Time extends `java.util.Date`) and then use that as per `java.util.Date#getTimezoneOffset` documentation:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(time);
long time = (calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + calendar.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)) / (60 * 1000);
```

Comment: `Calendar` doesn't extend `Date`.  That'd introduce even *more* broken and rage into the whole `java.util.Date` debacle.